# Every word in the sentence capital letter

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to write an regex expression for my task.
Every word in the sentence starts with a capital letter, the rest is lower case letter.

> ```
> (^[A-Z]{1}[a-z\s]+)+
> ```

e.g.

`Java Test` - ok

`Java test` - not ok

`JaVa Test` - not ok

`java Test` - not ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern you tried will also match `Java test` because the character class `[a-z\s]+` repeats 1+ times any of the listed including a space and does not force the second word to start with an uppercase char.

You could repeat the part matching an uppercase char followed by 1+ lower case chars for every iteration.

Note that `\s` will also match a newline and you can omit `{1}`

```
^[A-Z][a-z]+(?: [A-Z][a-z]+)*$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[A-Z][a-z]+` Match 1 uppercase A-Z and 1+ lowercase a-z
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `[A-Z][a-z]+` Match a space, 1 uppercase A-Z and 1+ lowercase chars a-z
- `)*` Close non capturing group and repeat 1+ times
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4AIVoq/1)

Instead of matching a single space you could also match 1+ horizonltal whitespace chars using `\h` (In java `\\h`)

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VxyYWA/1)

Answer (score 0):

If there can be single character in any of the words like :

```
This Is A Test
I Am A Programmer
```

then you can use :

```
^(\b[A-Z][a-z]*\s?\b)+$
```

Demo and explanation can be found [here](https://regex101.com/r/dmBcIg/6/)

Otherwise If there are always more than one character in every word, you can use :

```
^(\b[A-Z][a-z]+\s?\b)+$
```

Demo and explanation can be found [here](https://regex101.com/r/vwfn13/3/).